# How can I alert user, before redirect

Tags: javascript, php

I have a function where I get all information in my users. At the end of the string, I give the admin the option to delete the user, based on the users id.

My string:

```
while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc () ) {
   $string .= "<tr><td>" . $row ['id'] . "</td><td>" . $row ['first_name'] . "</td><td>" . $row ['last_name'] . "</td><td>" . $row ['email'] . "</td><td>" . $row ['role_name'] . "</td><td>[<a href='delete.php?id=" . $row ['id'] . "'>Delete</a>]</td></tr>";
}
```

My delete page:

```
if ($user->deleteUser($_GET['id']))
{
    header("Location: admin.php");
}
else
{
    echo "Could not delete the user!";
}
```

And my delete user function:

```
public function deleteUser($id)
{
    $sql = "DELETE FROM users WHERE id = ?";
    if (!$result = $this->db->mysqli->prepare($sql))
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (!$result->bind_param('i', $id))
    {
        return false;
    }

    return $result->execute();
}
```

And all of this works fine.

What I wan't to know, is how can I promt admin with an alert, saying: "Are you sure?" for example.

Comment: You need to do that before reaching the PHP. In other words, when the link is clicked/action performed.

Comment: or you can also implement two-queries step: confirm/action

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `confirm` js function:

```
<a href="delete.php?id=.." onclick="return confirm('are you sure?')">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript on click with your links. for example change

```
<a href='delete.php?id=".$row['id']"'>Delete</a>
```

to

```
<a href='delete.php?id=".$row['id']."' onclick='return confirm(\'are you sure?\')'>Delete</a>
```

this will call a javascript confirm box before you're taken to the link.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [vanillaJS](http://vanilla-js.com/) Framework for this:

```
if (confirm('Are you sure?')) {
  alert('deleted');
} else {
  alert('Cancelled');
}
```

Comment: Why on earth would you use a framework like this just to throw a confirm box? That's like buying an entire grocery store because you want a can of soup.

Comment: @PatrickQ, aha, lulz... please, read more about this framework))

Comment: Okay, good one. Although I think the humor/irony would be completely lost on someone who's asking a question like this.

Comment: And if you don't like the smell of vanilla, you could always try **[Vapor.js](https://github.com/madrobby/vapor.js)**.  It's got fairly similar features and its only 14% as large.

Comment: @ScottSauyet, it has obfuscated version, it is good for security reason)

Comment: @vp_arth: Yes, so does Vapor.  There is a difference, though.  When Vapor's obfuscation runs, it _reduces_ the code size another 11%.  Vanilla's strange obfuscation routine unfortunately nearly _doubles_ the size of the code.  Not that I'm complaining; they're both nice libraries.  But sometimes size really does matter!

Answer (score 0):

It's simple. Add the following code to your javascript.

```
 <a href='delete.php?id=" . $row ['id'] . "'onclick="deletPost()">Delete</a>
//Javascript
<script>
function deletePost() {
    var ask = window.confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this post?");
    if (ask) {
        //Do something if approved.
    }
}</script>
```